# Cassandra on windows - trouble running commands

Tags: cassandra

I just installed Casandra on my windows machine. When I run cassandra.bat everything seems to be ok - no errors, just some debug statement.

I then launch the client - cassandra-cli.bat, and no matter whet I type in at the command prompt (other that ?) I get back a ... with a tab and a bilking cursor.

The articles I have read say to type in: connect localhost/9160, but this yields the same result - just a ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading obsolete articles. Commands end with a semicolon now.  Look at the readme for a correct example.